# What are inittabBB and rcSBB?

Tags: linux, embedded

I am familiar with inittab and rc on a Linux system and I recently came across inittabBB and rcSBB files on an embedded Linux distribution. I cannot find any literature on the web.
What are the differences and how do they relate?

Comment: Perhaps it's related to busybox. (I'm unfamiliar with it, just a guess.)

Comment: I think you're into something here. Busybox is running on the system and the initials match :)